# i am trying to do linear search using recursion in python?

Tags: python, recursion

[my code of linear search using recursion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4OWS.png)

recursion is not stopping when targeted element is found

```
def checkNumber(arr, x):
    l  = len(arr)
    if(arr[0]==x):
        return True
    else:
        return
    smallerarr = arr[1:]
    is_xpresent = checkNumber(smallerarr,x)

    return is_xpresent
```

Comment: If the first element in the list is not `x` then the function returns (None) without performing any recursion

Comment: The code is somewhat incorrect. The recursion will stop in any case at the first invocation because you always return from the ```checkNumber``` function. See here: ```if(arr[0]==x):
        return True
    else:
        return```

Comment: In addition to the remarks above, what happens if the element isn't in the list? Welcome to SO, by the way!

Comment: @IainShelvington sir even after it returns none then it goes for the next part of array to check for targeted element which in case if not there final answer comes to be False even if it was present in previous part of the list

Comment: A function does not continue after it returns, once it returns it stops running

Comment: @ggorlen if the ele is not in list it return nothing and in the main code return nothing by checkNumber function prints false

Comment: @IainShelvington sir then what correction is needed in my code/??

Comment: [Check](https://repl.it/repls/WorthwhileImpeccableTerabyte) this. I added comments in the code to make it easy for you to understand.

Comment: I meant to suggest that the current code crashes when the element isn't there because it tries an out of bounds `arr[0]` without checking the base case of an empty list.

Comment: Please don't add a picture of your code but add it as text, so people reviewing your question can easily try your code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the recursive call in your else block, otherwise you are exiting out of the function too early. You also need a failure/break condition, this is when arr is an empty list either because the entire list has been searched or an empty list was passed, in this case return `False`

```
def checkNumber(arr, x):
    if not arr:  # Simple/failure case where arr is an empty list
        return False
    elif arr[0] == x:
        return True
    else:
        return checkNumber(arr[1:], x)
```